# copy-list-initialization when initializing objects

Tags: c++, c++14

```c++
  struct Box {
        Box() { puts("default"); }
        Box(Box const&) { puts("copy"); }
        Box(int, float) { puts("int, float"); }
        Box(int) { puts("int"); }
        Box(Box&&) { puts("move"); }
    }

Box box1 = {34}; // chooses Box(int) copy-list-initialization
Box box2 = 34; // chooses Box(int) copy initialization

// But if -fno-elide-constructors flag been used, 
   // box1 prints only int
   // box2 prints int and move
```

- Why move constructor is not called in the case of box1 being initialized with a temporary?
- if initializer_list constructor is provided which takes int eg( Box(std::initializer_list) {} ), braced init list always calls init list c'tor. why? using c++ 14 clang

Comment: "*if initializer_list constructor is thrown which takes int*" What does that mean? Particularly "is thrown"?

Comment: It would improve the question to post a Minimal, Reproducible Example and explain how the output differs from what you expected